Indicator swap animation in jetpack compose
I'm trying to implement this animation using animateIntOffsetAsState, but it has not helped to achieve this. (I may not be good at this). I will share my current implementation and how it works. It would be good if someone could help me achieve this.
I want to achieve this:

But this is how it currently is:

Our designer is quite okay with this. But let me try to find the tech behind this. Please help.
@Composable
fun PageIndicator(
    isSelected: Boolean,
    selectedColor: Color,
    defaultColor: Color,
    defaultRadius: Dp,
    selectedLength: Dp,
    animationDurationInMillis: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    val color: Color by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) {
            selectedColor
        } else {
            defaultColor
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationDurationInMillis,
        )
    )
    val width: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) {
            selectedLength
        } else {
            defaultRadius
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationDurationInMillis,
        )
    )

    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(
                width = width,
                height = defaultRadius,
            ),
    ) {
        drawRoundRect(
            color = color,
            topLeft = Offset.Zero,
            size = Size(
                width = width.toPx(),
                height = defaultRadius.toPx(),
            ),
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(
                x = defaultRadius.toPx(),
                y = defaultRadius.toPx(),
            ),
        )
    }
}


Which animation would you like to achieve using the code you included? The first or the second gif?

@OmarSahl: That information was actually already part of the question, just not visible without looking at the questions source. I edited the question to make it explicit.
